# Jetpack Compose - center composable with another composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a row with Image on the start of the row, and a Column with 2 Text compassable items next to the image.

I want to have the column aligned to the image, so if the second text is empty, I want to have the first Text centered to the Image.

In constraint layout, I would set the column to topOf Image and to BottomOf Image, so I wonder how to do it with compose.

```
Surface(color = Color(0xff2d4466).copy(alpha = 0.9f)) {
    Row(
        Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {

        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(iconUrl)
                .crossfade(true)
                .diskCacheKey(iconUrl)
                .scale(Scale.FIT)
                .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
                .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .build(),
            placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_outgoing),
            error = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_outgoing),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
                .size(32.dp)
                
        )

        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp)) {
            Text(text = "First Row", color = Color.White)
            Text(text = "Second Row", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer - Intrinsic measurements - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements**

Intrinsic measurements allow you to fill the space available, without constraint layout. You need to apply Max intrinsic height to the parent layouts and weights to the children.

Row and Column come with alignment / arrangement params that allow you to center the content. So something like this:

```
   Surface(color = Color(0xff2d4466).copy(alpha = 0.9f)) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(all = 8.dp)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        AsyncImage(
            model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                .data(iconUrl)
                .crossfade(true)
                .diskCacheKey(iconUrl)
                .scale(Scale.FIT)
                .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
                .networkCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.DISABLED)
                .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
                .build(),
            placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_outgoing),
            error = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_outgoing),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp)
                .size(32.dp)

        )

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp)
                .weight(1f),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            Text(text = "First Row", color = Color.White)
            Text(text = "Second Row", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}
```

Compose also has it's own version of constraint layout but it would probably be overkill in this use case - [Compose constraint layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/constraintlayout)